# In Postgres is it possible to retrieve distinct date data if the table only contains the datetime field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The data is stored as follows

```
2011-04-29 11:35:24.567
```

I would like a query SELECT DISTINCT ...

That will return data along the lines of

```
2011-04-28
2011-04-29
2011-04-30
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to cast it as date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    col_name::date
FROM
    table_name
```